# ng-repeat not showing items in array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using AngularJS and I'm trying to use `ng-repeat`, but I can't get it to work.

My view looks like this:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="addWidget('blaat')">Widget 1</a>

<div ng-repeat="widget in widgets">
    A: {{widget.url}}
</div>
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
.controller('PageController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.widgets = [];

    $scope.addWidget = function($widgetUrl) {
        $scope.widgets.push({
            url: $widgetUrl
        });

        console.log($scope.widgets);
    }
}])
```

When I press on the `href` link then it should add an item to the `widgets` array and `ng-repeat` should pick that up. But I don't see anything appear in my view.

But I do see that `console.log` is printing the right values to console. So my controller functiojn IS working. Then is my `ng-repeat` not showing anything?

---

You can view my demo here: http://ngrepeat.byethost7.com/#/page

This was the only way I could reproduce it. *(if you see ads at first, then simply refresh the page. It's a free host)*

Comment: Can you repro in a plunkr or fiddle?

Comment: Have you declared `ng-controller="PagesController"` attribute, and `ng-app` on a parent element?

Comment: Yes create a repro in plunkr or fiddle.

Comment: @AlexW No I haven't. I assume that my route instantiates the right controller for me? Route: `$routeProvider.when('/page', {templateUrl: 'page.html', controller: 'PageController'});` Because I can also trigger the controller function with no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine if you remove the `href="#"` from the anchor. The hash is causing your page to reload fresh each time it is clicked. Either remove the `href="#"` or perhaps consider changing your anchor to a button if page navigation is not actually happening.

Comment: Ah lol, so that was the problem the whole time. It indeed works when I change `#` to `javascript:;`. Any idea why this problem doesn't occur in sylwester's example? He also has a hashtag in his hyperlink.

Comment: I suspect it's due to this commit: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/f3de5b6eac90baf649506072162f36dbc6d2f028